# UITextView should detect links, but otherwise, should propagate touch to view below

Tags: ios, uiview, touch

I have a text view, where I want to detect links, but when there isn't a link at the touch point, it should propagate the touch to view below (it currently doesn't). It will be contained in a table view cell, and if the user taps a link, it should interact (it works), but when another point is tapped, it should select the table view cell.

I needed text to be unselectable, so I've followed https://stackoverflow.com/a/27264999/811405 and implemented:

```
-(BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder{
    return NO;
}
```

It wasn't sending the touch events below before that too, but I've included it just is case it interferes with a solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of preventing your text view from becoming first responder, you need to subclass the `hitTest` method so that it returns the textView when the click occured inside a link and return nil otherwise.

```
@interface LinkOnlyTextView : UITextView
@end

@implementation LinkOnlyTextView

- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSUInteger glyphIndex = [self.layoutManager glyphIndexForPoint:point inTextContainer:self.textContainer fractionOfDistanceThroughGlyph:nullptr];
    NSUInteger characterIndex = [self.layoutManager characterIndexForGlyphAtIndex:glyphIndex];
    if (characterIndex < self.textStorage.length) {
        if ([self.textStorage attribute:NSLinkAttributeName atIndex:characterIndex effectiveRange:nullptr]) {
            return self;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}

@end
```

There is a Swift version of this code snippet provided by @blwinters in a later answer to this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47913329/1279096

Comment: it worked, though there is a small typo in your method, correcting it... (and I'll award the bounty when SO allows me to)

Comment: This works for most cases but it needs a little modification to work in all cases. characterIndexForGlyphAtIndex returns the nearest character to the point so even if you are not touching the link this could still detect that the link is touched. Once you have the glyphIndex you then need to get the glyphRect and detect if the point is in that. CGRect glyphRect = [self.layoutManager boundingRectForGlyphRange:NSMakeRange(glyphIndex, 1) inTextContainer:self.textContainer];
if (CGRectContainsPoint(glyphRect, point))...

Comment: In my case, this code crash if text length is 0. Just skip this test if self.text.length == 0

Comment: @slobodans : Thanks, I've updated the code according to your comment.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a Swift version of @Dalzhim's answer, incorporating the adjustment from @jupham to check that `point` is actually contained within `glyphRect`.

```
override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {

    let glyphIndex = self.layoutManager.glyphIndex(for: point, in: self.textContainer)

    //Ensure the glyphIndex actually matches the point and isn't just the closest glyph to the point
    let glyphRect = self.layoutManager.boundingRect(forGlyphRange: NSRange(location: glyphIndex, length: 1), in: self.textContainer)

    if glyphIndex < self.textStorage.length,
        glyphRect.contains(point),
        self.textStorage.attribute(NSAttributedStringKey.link, at: glyphIndex, effectiveRange: nil) != nil {

        return self
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```